# Generate external link for Document download

Tags: apex, document

I'm trying to generate an external download link for a Document record I've created previosly on my org.

I've tried with

```
URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm() + '/sfc/servlet.shepherd/document/download/' + documentID
```

But it's not working. I've also tried with the body URL but it gives me a file with the base64 Body of the document instead of the actual file

```
'/services/data/v51.0/sobjects/Document/' + documentID + '/Body'
```

Is there a way I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You are asking about the old Document object, which does not appear to be supported in lightning.

This question is basically a duplicate of [Access Document(pdf or doc) without Salesforce login](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/92676/access-documentpdf-or-doc-without-salesforce-login). The answers there are still relevant to you, especially considering that you are still in classic.